# Get 2 Divs in one box?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I would get 2 divs in one div

[image]

```css
html {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
}

#navbar {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #080808 !important;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 31px;
  height: 90px !important;
  width: 90px !important;
}

.navitems li,
.navitems ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navitems {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="90px" height="90px">
  </div>
  <div class="navitems">
    <li>
      <ul><a href="#">Home</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="#team">Contact Us</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="#about">About</a></ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `float`, the floating items must be placed before "regular" (non-floating) items in the DOM tree. In this instance, you would want to move your `<div class="navitems">` before `<div class="logo">`. Also, you might want to permutate your `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. `<ul>` contains `<li>`s, not the other way around. ;)

Comment: Could you provide more info about the messing up?
Here is a JSFiddle that should help: https://jsfiddle.net/dsn0bop9/

Comment: Please try the code from the jsFiddle I linked right above, or supply your updated code.

Comment: Why thankyou very much that jsFiddle solved the problem! :*

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to use flex.

Set "display: flex" and "justify-content: space-between" on the parent element (navigator).  I also changed the image to just have a background color that stands out.

```css
html {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
}

#navbar {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #080808 !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  background-color: #0ff;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 31px;
  height: 90px !important;
  width: 90px !important;
}

.navitems li,
.navitems ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img width="90px" height="90px">
  </div>
  <div class="navitems">
    <li>
      <ul><a href="#">Home</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="#team">Contact Us</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="#about">About</a></ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on flex properties:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The 2 divs are in 1 div only but the fact is float property does not changes the flow .Floated elements remain a part of the flow of the web page unlike absolute and fixed positioning so place the div class="navitems" above the div class="logo".Moreover interchange the ul and li you have used them incorrectly conceptually although it doesnt make any difference visually

Answer (score 0):

First, use `display: inline-block;` on those two DIVs. Also, use `vertical-align: middle;` on both to align them vertically centered to their container.

But there a mistake in your code: `ul` and `li` should be used the other way round, the `li`s are *inside*  the `ul` . And also note that `list-style-type: none;` is only assigned to the `ul`, and `display: inline-block;`  only to the `li` elements.

```css
#navbar {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #080808 !important;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 31px;
  height: 90px !important;
  width: 90px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navitems {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navitems ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navitems li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90/fb4" alt="" width="90px" height="90px">
  </div>
  <div class="navitems">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```